# How can Cat Swarm Algorithm (CSO) used for feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, swarm-intelligence, cat-swarm-optimization

Cat swarm optimization (CSO) is a novel metaheuristic for evolutionary optimization algorithms based on swarm intelligence which proposed in 2006. See [Feature Selection of Support Vector Machine Based on Harmonious Cat Swarm Optimization](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6916353).

According to [Modified Cat Swarm Optimization Algorithm for Feature Selection of Support Vector Machines](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/288068152_Modified_Cat_Swarm_Optimization_Algorithm_for_Feature_Selection_of_Support_Vector_Machines)

> CSO imitates the behavior of cats through two sub-modes: seeking and tracing. Previous studies have indicated that CSO algorithms outperform other well-known meta-heuristics, such as genetic algorithms and particle swarm optimization. This study presents a modified version of cat swarm optimization (MCSO), capable of improving search efficiency within the problem space. The basic CSO algorithm was integrated with a local search procedure as well as the feature selection of support vector machines (SVMs).

Can someone explain how exactly Cat Swarm Algorithm (CSO) is used for feature selection?